# Google webmasters duplicate description due to .php extension

Tags: .htaccess, seo, google-search-console

Google webmasters tool is showing me 26 duplicate pages because you can access the page
in both ways:
/crossMaker.php?jsonID=103
/crossMaker?jsonID=103

In my htaccess file i made it possible not to include the php extension but
probably somewhere in the code i linked to the filename with the suffix so google crawled
it.

What can i do so that google will forget about the file with the extension? use 301 redirect? if so how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [canoncial URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html). It's *much* easier and the proper way to handle this.

For example, put this at the top of the page:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/crossMaker?jsonID=103" />
```

You can create these dynamically so it should be easy for you to implement.